# Splitting a column into two does not work properly or not at all

Tags: split, tidyverse, stringr

I have a big data frame with 10 variables and thousand of objectives and want to split the time stamp (which is the first column) into date and time.

I tried different codes so far, like the stringr and the tidyverse package, but all I get is two different results:

1. nothing happens at all, but also no error code appears (for tidyverse)
2. it splits the time stamp how I want it, but cuts of all the other columns, so I just have the date and time left (for stringr)

> ```
> bubble_data %>%
>   separate(Time, into = c('Date', 'Time'), sep = " ") %>%
> ```

> ```
> str_split_fixed(bubble_data$Time," ", 2)
> ```

Thats the two codes I tried.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a good idea to show us a small sample of your date variable. Also, generally, it's easiest to use the `lubridate` package for date/time manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, starting with a data frame containing date/times stored in a character vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Time, 
  "2011-06-04 12:05:00", 
  "2013-12-19 15:21:12", 
  "2017-01-30 06:47:53"
)

df %>% 
  mutate(TimeStamp = lubridate::ymd_hms(Time), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  mutate(
    Date = lubridate::as_date(TimeStamp),
    Time = hms::as_hms(TimeStamp)
  )

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  TimeStamp           Date       Time    
  <dttm>              <date>     <time>  
1 2011-06-04 12:05:00 2011-06-04 12:05:00
2 2013-12-19 15:21:12 2013-12-19 15:21:12
3 2017-01-30 06:47:53 2017-01-30 06:47:53
```